# Is it possible to play Rock Band with multiple accounts from the same machine?

Tags: ps3, rock-band-3

In Rock Band 3 for PS3, when I'm playing with a band locally, is there a way that I can save my progress to the character on my account, even if that account isn't the currently active one?  Like if my son is playing on his account, can I somehow join the game as the character from my account (on the same machine) and have it save achievements accordingly, similar to games like Little Big Planet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching on the Rock Band forums, I found [this post](http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?t=204297&page=1) which seems to confirm that it is not possible on PS3.  So only one account can be achieving goals at a time (although you can choose whether you want to have multiple people achieving goals for that one account).

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tested this specific case, but whenever a player joins a current session, there's an option to sign in with any account that's not currently playing. You can also change the account you are using between songs, by pressing start.

Comment: Are you basing this off the PS3 version?  I'm not seeing that show up, and when I go to Characters under the menu, it only shows the one for the currently active account.